# Error when Communicating with the server while Cluster Setup in Cloudera

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am  trying to up Hadoop in Centos-7 usign CLoudera, but while Cluster Setup process (Single node), I am getting this error stating:

> There was an error when communicating with the server. See the log file for more information.

[image]
I logged into `cloudera-scm-agent.log` file using

```
sudo cat /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/cloudera-scm-agent.log
```

And I see Failed directory creation and connection refused errors.
The detailed log file can be found [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=21984184703196285530).

Can someone please assist me on what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the cluster with single user mode? if so the system user "cloudera-scm" should have permission to perform read, write operation on service log, pid, data directory. From your log message, all services are refused to start because of improper file system permission.

```html
stacks', u'bytes_free_warning_threshhold_bytes': 0, u'group': u'cloudera-scm', u'user': u'cloudera-scm', u'mode': 493}]
[01/Nov/2018 04:41:11 +0000] 28095 MainThread os_ops       ERROR    Failed directory creation: /var/log/zookeeper/stacks: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/zookeeper'
[01/Nov/2018 04:41:11 +0000] 28095 MainThread process      ERROR    Could not evaluate resource {u'path': u'/var/log/zookeeper/stacks', u'bytes_free_warning_threshhold_bytes': 0, u'group': u'cloudera-scm', u'user': u'cloudera-scm', u'mode': 493}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmf-5.15.1-py2.7.egg/cmf/process.py", line 963, in _do_directory_resources
    self.osops.mkabsdir(d["path"], user=d["user"], group=d["group"], mode=d["mode"])
  File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmf-5.15.1-py2.7.egg/cmf/util/os_ops.py", line 180, in mkabsdir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/zookeeper'
```